# Apollo is not caching data correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

I have an app where if I flick between different weeks I request data for the specific data range (sort of like a calendar). When my app first loads it requests data to the server (obviously) and then if go to the next week it makes the same request but with different variables (server obviously again) but if I then flick back a week it makes a request again to the server, however, I thought it would go to the cache this time as the current (3rd) query is identical to the (1st) query I performed.

Does apollo require me doing any extra setup with `client.writeQuery` or `client.readQuery`

The docs make it sound like I don't but I'm not sure how to handle this. I also will need the app to make a server request 1-2seconds after I land on a new week just to ensure all the data is up to date

I can show code but it's just a super simple query getting data and wondering why it's duplicating identical queries to the network

Answer (score 0):

You can control how Apollo uses the cache using a [fetchPolicy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#setting-a-fetch-policy)

It sounds like in your case you want a network request on the first request and a cache-only on the next one. You can use:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only', // Used for first execution
  nextFetchPolicy: 'cache-first', // Used for subsequent executions
});
```

The request will still go to the server every time but your data will be loaded from cache *first* on the 2nd and subsequent executions before the cache is refreshed from the network.